# Only print strings starting with a given letter / Python

Tags: startswith

## print cites from visited_cities list in alphabetical order using .sort()

## only print cities that names start "Q" or earlier (meaning a to q)

visited_cities = ["New York", "Shanghai", "Munich", "Toyko", "Dubai", "Mexico City", "São Paulo", "Hyderabad"]

the .sort() was easy to do but I don't know how figure out the second part of the problem.

Comment: is this Python?

Comment: What do you mean by earlier?

Comment: Have you done any research on the remaining portion of your assignment?

Comment: Yes, Python code. Earlier means from "A" to "Q"

Comment: The first 3 lines are the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it with regular expressions and filtering like:

```
import re
regex=re.compile('[A-Q]{1}.*')
cities = list(filter(lambda city: re.match(regex, city), visited_cities))
print(*cities, sep='\n')
```

the regex variable looks for any city starting from [A-Q]

there is even an easier solution by utilizing the Unicode code point of a character. look at the method [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

```
for city in visited_cities:
     first_character = city[0]
     if ord(first_character) >= ord('A') and ord(first_character) <= ord('Q'):
             print(city)
```

the Unicode code points are ordered so an A is at 65, B is at 66 ... Q is at 81 ... Z is at 90. so if you want to print only those cities starting with letters from A to Q you have to make sure their Unicode code point is between 65 and 81

Comment: It works perfectly fine. I was expecting something more basic since it is Python for beginners but thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: I added a more basic version